# ASP.NET button event is fired but row in SQL database is not affected

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql, jquery-ui

I am trying to search over StackOverflow regarding this issues, but it seems like haven solve my problem.

I am clicking asp.net button in jQuery ui-dialog and affect SQL Server database, it does not work for me below is my code for the javascript, aspx and C# code

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#create-new-user").dialog
    ({
        title: "CREATE NEW USER",
        open: function (event, ui) 
        { 
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); //disable close button
        }, 
        open: function(type, data)
        {
            $this.parent().appendTo("form:first");
        },
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 1000,
        hight:600,
    }); //to open div content


    $("#CreateNewUserButton").click(function () {

        $("#create-new-user").dialog("open");
    }); //for button

    $("#edit-user").dialog
    ({
        title: "EDIT USER",
        open: function (event, ui) 
        { 
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); //disable close button
        }, 
        open: function(type, data)
        {
            $this.parent().appendTo("form:first");
        },
        autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 1000,
        hight:600,
    }); //to open div content

    $("#EditUserOpener").click(function () {
        $("#edit-user").dialog("open");
    }); //for button

    //different tag can be separate
    $("#newclosedialog").click(function () {
        $("#create-new-user").dialog("close")});

    $("#editclosedialog").click(function (){
        $("#edit-user").dialog("close")});
    });
});
```

C# button function:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

string command = "DECLARE @totalcount INT" +
                 "DECLARE @count VARCHAR(10)" +
                 "SELECT @totalcount=(SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM User)" + /*This one is used to return total number of records in table */
                 "IF @totalcount IS NULL" +     /*Condition to check whether totalcount contains value or not*/
                 "SET @count='0000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),3000)" +
                 "ELSE" +
                 "SET @count='0000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 3000+(@totalcount))" +
                 "INSERT INTO Users(ID, Username, Password, ConfirmPassword, ActiveRole, Status, BaseCurrency, FullName, EmailAddress, LoginRestriction, Remarks)" +
                        "VALUES(@count, @Username, @Password, @ConfirmPassword, @ActiveRole, @Status, @BaseCurrency, @FullName, @EmailAddress, @LoginRestriction, @Remarks)";

SqlCommand adduser = new SqlCommand(command, conn);
adduser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", NewUsernameTextBox);
adduser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", NewPasswordTextBox);
adduser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConfirmPassword", NewConfirmPasswordTextBox);
adduser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActiveRole", NewActiveRoleDropDownList);
adduser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", NewStatusRadioButtonList);
adduser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BaseCurrancy", NewBaseCurrancyDropDownList);
adduser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", NewFullNameTextBox);
adduser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", NewEmailTextBox);
adduser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginRestriction", NewLoginCheckBox);
adduser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", NewRemarksTextBox);

try
{
    adduser.ExecuteNonQuery();

    int dataffect = adduser.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (dataffect == 1)
        Label1.Text = "new user added";

    Label1.Visible = true;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Label1.Text = "something wrong";
    Label1.Visible = true;
}

conn.Close();
```

Aspx markup for the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Create User" 
                        ValidationGroup="1" onclick="Button1_Click"   
UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

Comment: First of all identify the bugged section: are there any js error (check chrome dev tool console)? Does button event handler method have all needed data? is try-catch section executing without exceptions?

Comment: @Alberto already check, all the data required for the button is call and is fill in and check the function of try-catch

Comment: Good, so the problem is not client but server side. Now: what does adduser.ExecuteNonQuery() returns (what's the value of dataffect)?

Comment: @Alberto the function of adduser.ExecuteNonQuery() is ensure the data was added to database and int dataaffect is to identify the data is added or not if not added than it will catch the exception